How to write a correct regex to get the string I want
I have a string which is txt = "$2024122201200}" or txt = "$2024122201200", and I want to get the string 2024122201200.
I tried as below,
import re

x = re.findall("\$(.*)(?=}{0,1})", txt)
print(x)

but the output is ['2024122201200}'], while actually I want ['2024122201200']. To my understanding, it should be working.
Here the sample is all digit, but actually it's digit/character all possible.
I tried to replace the parameter which define in config xml, like ${currenttime} or ${currentbalance-300}, but sometimes this parameter can be $currenttime or $currentbalance -300, so I need to write regex to match it.

Why not \d+ which means "one or more consecutive digits" ?

@JohnGordon I guess there are other unwanted \d+ patterns in txts.

What details or clarity does this need? Seems fine to me...

@nocomment I don't see why you would need that information to answer the question. Frankly, I had an answer I was about to post to this before it was closed and 2 other users have suggestions. There is clearly enough details and clarity to be answerable.

@Starship-OnDiscussionsStrike One can wonder what the possible inputs exactly are. If it's always a $ sign, 12 digits and maybe a }, then something like txt[1:13] or txt.strip('$}') would be enough. But one can imagine that the OP chose to use a regex instead of these evident solutions because not all inputs have this format. We don't know, so the question can be considered unclear.

@nocomment many good answers are posted with rhetorical questions. Do you believe all those people also want that question closed

@ThierryLathuille You are making an assumption and then saying that if that was correct, the question is unclear. What about reading the question as is and seeing if, just with what is actually In the question, it is answerable

What should the result be for ${currentbalance-300}? {currentbalance-300 or currentbalance-300?

There's no need to use a regexp for this.
Just remove } from the end and $ and { from the beginning. These can be done using the strip methods.
txt = "$2024122201200}"
result = txt.rstrip('}')
result = result.lstrip('${')
print(result)


How about just txt.strip('${}')?

That's also a possibility, although it will remove $ at the end as well.

Alternative of }{0,1} is }* : zero or more occurrence
You may use this:
import re

txt = "$2024122201200}"
x = re.sub(r'\$(\d+)[}]*', r'\1', txt)
print(x)

txt = "$2024122201200"
x1 = re.sub(r'\$(\d+)[}]*', r'\1', txt)
print(x1)

https://www.programiz.com/online-compiler/0fkwe2zixyrrQ
if you want to use findall method then solution is:
import re

txt = "$2024122201200}"
x = re.findall(r"\$(\d+)(?=}*)", txt) # return multiple match
print(x[0])  # print first match

txt = "$2024122201200"
x = re.findall(r"\$(\d+)(?=}*)", txt) 
print(x[0])


From the question: "Here the sample is all digit, but actually it's digit/character all possible." Your solution only works with digits.

not mention by writer. But if it's digits/characters then need to add \w+ or [a-zA-Z0-9]  in place of \d+

Why do you say it's not mentioned? They gave more examples like ${currenttime} and ${currenttime-300}

That case need to mention the valid pattern which need to allow... So, your solution is best for that case...  @Barmar  Thanks for pointing out my mistake
